# Can a salt master provide a state to unavailable minions?

Tags: salt-stack

**Background**: I have several servers which run a service I develop. All of them should have the same copy of the service.

To ensure deployment and up-to-dateness I use Ansible, with an idempotent  playbook which deploys the service. Since the servers are on an unreliable network, I have to run the playbook periodically (in a cron job) to reach the servers which may not have been available before.

**Problem**: I was under the impression that the SaltStack philosophy is different: I though I could just *"set a state, compile it and offer to a set of minions. These minions would then, at their own leisure, come to the master and get whatever they need to do"*.

This does not seem to be the case: the minions which were not available at deployment time are skipped.

**Question**: is there a mechanism which would allow for an asynchronous deployment, in the sense that a state set on the master **one time only** would then be pulled and applied by the minions (to themselves) once they are ready / can reach the master?

Specifically, without the need to continuously re-offer the same state to all minions, in the hope that the ones which were unavailable in the past are now capable to get the update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time a minion connects to the master there is an event on the event bus which you can react upon.

[Reactor](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/reactor/#mapping-events-to-reactor-sls-files)

This is the main difference between Ansible and Saltstack.

In order to do what you want, I would react on each minion's reconnect and try to apply a state which is idempotent.

[Idempotent](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/reactor/#mapping-events-to-reactor-sls-files)

You could also setup a scheduled task in Saltstack that runs the state every X minutes and apply the desired configuration.

[Scheduled task](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/reactor/#mapping-events-to-reactor-sls-files)

Answer (score -1):

The [answer](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/45813#issuecomment-362304134) from [Daniel Wallace](https://github.com/gtmanfred) (salt developper):

> That is not possible.
>
> The minions connect to the publish port/bus and the master puts new
>   jobs on that bus. Then the minion picks it up and runs the job, if the
>   minion is not connected when the job is published, then it will not
>   see the job.

Comment: just because the guy says it, doesn't mean its right. he probably didn't pay attention to what you wanted to do or didn't read my reply. I am also a saltstack contributor btw and the below answer is the one that fits your use case. Minions will try to apply the state with a scheduled job even if they are not connected to the master or with reactor master will try to apply state as soon as minion connects.
You didn't even comment on why my answer is wrong and take a copy paste from another guy who provides no explanation.

Comment: I am back to this five years later and I changed the accepted answer. It still surprises me that there is no simple mechanism to publish states and have the minions consume it. I understand your answer, though - and will do that now that I am back on the topic.